# $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite cohomological dimension; then why is $\operatorname{Ext}^i(R,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=0$ for $i>0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm a little confused about the following:

In my notes, it is said that the category $R$-mod, for $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite cohomological dimension, where $p$ is a prime number. In particular, for the $R$-module $M=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, we have an injective resolution
$$0\to M\xrightarrow{p\cdot} R\xrightarrow{p\cdot} R\to \cdots.$$

I wanted to calculate $\operatorname{Ext}^i(R,M)$. To do this, we apply the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,-)$ and take the cohomology of the complex; but on applying the functor, we get a complex
$$0\to M\xrightarrow{p\cdot} R\xrightarrow{p\cdot} R\to \cdots$$

again as $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)\cong M$. This is exact and so $\operatorname{Ext}^i(R,M)=0$ for $i>0$.

This doesn't seem to comply with the fact that $R$-Mod has infinite cohomological dimension, as then for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\operatorname{Ext}^i(N,N')\neq 0$ for some $i>n$ and $N,N'\in R$-Mod.

I believe I have made a grave error in my reasoning somewhere, and I was hoping to understand where. I believe it may have to do with the maps of the complex. Thank you so much, any help will be much appreciated.

Sidenote: in my notes, its said that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,M)\cong M$ for all $i$... Why is this true? I couldn't get anything reasonable taking cohomology.

**EDIT**

I've understood my error in understanding with the help of the comment. as for my sidenote, I'm struggling to compute the it still:

Applying $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,-)$ to the resolution, we get a complex
$$0\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)\xrightarrow{d_1} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)\xrightarrow{d_2} \cdots.$$

As all $R$-homomorphisms from $M$ are determined by the image of $1$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)\cong M$ and so $\operatorname{Ext}^0(M,M)\cong M$. For higher $i$, we have that $\ker d_2/ \operatorname{im}d_1=\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,M)\cong\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,M)$. Further, the maps $d_1$ and $d_2$ are given by post-multiplication by $p$, that is, $d_i:\alpha\mapsto p\cdot \alpha$. Again, the image if $1$ determines the homomorphism $M\to R$ and so $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)\cong R$; so, $\ker d_1\cong (p)$ as if $1$ is mapped to an element in $(p)$ by a homomorphism, $d_1$ would map such a homomorphism to the zero homomorphism. Similarly, the image $d_2$ must also be $(p)$... but then this would mean that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,M)=0$... **where am I going wrong again?**

Comment: Infinite cohomological dimension just means that for any n, you can find $N$ and $N'$ such that $\text{Ext}^i(N,N') \not=0$  for some $i>n$. It need not hold for any choice of $N, N'$ (and in fact doesn't, when $N'$ is injective or $N$ projective).

Comment: As for the side note, compute Ext by using the infinite injective resolution of $M=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ that you have.

Comment: Ah! I see... I seem to have misunderstood the definition of cohomological dimension, thank you. For we say a category has cohomological dimension $k$ if all $p>k$ $\operatorname{Ext}^p(X,Y)=0$ for all objects $X,Y$; the negation of this statement, that is when the dimension is infinite, would require for each $p$ there to be some objects $X,Y$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^p(X,Y)=0$. Correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: Alright, I'll try to compute Ext again and see if I come short. Thank you!

Comment: @I'mRepresentable, please see my edit; I seem to be stuck with this computation...

Comment: Hom(M,R) is not R. The image of 1 should have order p in R.